# Is $P(X < Y \mid X = c) = P(c < Y)$?

Tags: probability

Let $X, Y$ be random variables, and $c$ be a constant.

It seems obvious to me that

$$P(X < Y \mid X = c) = P(c < Y)$$

but I'm not sure how to formally show this is true.

**Edit**:

It was helpfully pointed out that this is only true if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Now I am interested in the question of how to show the above equality in the independent case.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? Consider case that $X$=$Y$, than it is not true.

Comment: @iiivooo : Could you write $X=Y$ instead of $X$=$Y$?  Alternating in and out of MathJax like that is not proper usage and makes you see things that look like $X$=$Y$ instead of $X=Y$, with mismatches in fonts an sizes, and lack of proper spacing.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for noticing! I have no idea why I wrote it in such strange way. Time to go to bed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not necessarily true.   Suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed over $\{0,1\}$ and $Y=X$. Then:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<Y\mid X=0) ~=&~ 0
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(0<Y) ~=&~\tfrac 1 2\end{align}$$

It is only true when $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.   Otherwise all you can say is:$$\mathsf P(X<Y\mid X=c) ~=~ \mathsf P(c<Y\mid X=c)$$

Comment: First by 37 seconds:-)

Comment: Can you explain 1. how the last equation is derived (is "substituting" $c$ for $X$ legal?) and 2. how $P(c < Y | X = c) =P(c < Y)$ is true if $X, Y$ are independent? Obviously $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\implies P(Y|X) = P(Y)$, but the inequality $c < Y$ is confusing.

Comment: If $Y=X$, then since $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, wouldn't the probability that $Y$ is strictly greater than $1$ be $0$?

Comment: @Brenton The discrete set $\{0,1\}$ is not the continuous interval $[0;1]$.  But otherwise, yes, I used the wrong $c$

Comment: @GrahamKemp That is true, but I still don't see why that makes $P(1 < Y) =\frac{1}{2}$ if $Y$ can only take on values of $0$ and $1$

Comment: graham kemp i too have the same question?? why is $P(Y>1)=\frac {1}{2}$

Comment: @jayelm 1; When given that $X=c$ in the condition, then $X\leftarrow c$ is a valid substitution in the event.  2: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then knowing the value of $X$ does not impact the probability distribution of $Y$.